# how do I check for a column being non-nullable?

Tags: postgresql

As in topic, I would like to know how can I check for a column being non-nullable?
For oracle I have:

```
SELECT Nullable
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'TOP_VALIDATION_RULE'
AND column_name = 'ERROR_LEVEL'
```

but how to transform it for postgresql?

I tried something like this, but getting ERROR: column "is_nullable" does not exist:

```
SELECT is_nullable
FROM  information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'TOP_VALIDATION_RULE'
AND column_name = 'ERROR_LEVEL'
```

///EDIT
After modification:

```
SELECT is_nullable
    FROM  information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'TOP_VALIDATION_RULE'
    AND column_name = 'ERROR_LEVEL'
```

I get:

[image]

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added edit with attempt to do it with what you've pasted

Comment: So you have the solution, then what is your question?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it does not work :( I get ERROR: column "is_nullable" does not exist

Comment: You need to use the view  `columns`, not `tables`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ye, its true, but now, how can I specific table name and column name? I'm asking because I get 0 result.  (neither YES nor NO). If I remove WHERE table_name = 'TOP_VALIDATION_RULE'
AND column_name = 'ERROR_LEVEL' then I get column with YES/NO, but from all columns. Edited my post.

Comment: Table and column names are stored in lower case in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, it's true. Thhanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Use `pg_attribute` to check the column is `NULLABLE OR NOT`

```
SELECT attnotnull FROM  pg_attribute WHERE attname = 'ERROR_LEVEL'
```

Note: The above query will return more than one row if the `ERROR_LEVEL` column appears in more than one table in the database.